# Measuring effects between two times series (one time series on another)

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I'd like to see if a nations overall consumption can be tied to a specific retail company's sales. E.g. does the sales follow the nation-wide consumption pattern? Both datasets are time-series.

What types of models could be suited to examine this relationship and is it possible to measure, how positive/negative fluctuations impact the sales?

I've looked into VAR models and Granger-causality, but I'm not really how well-suited that framework is :-)

Data example is listed below - Consumer Confidence Index is an indicator of the national economy. Consumtion is sales from a specific retail company in that country. I want to investigate the effects between these two series - more specific: Is the **Consumption** affected by the **CCI** and how to which extend? E.g. if there's a downfall in CCI, how long after is Consumption affected?

```
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| YearMonth | Consumer Confidence Index |     Consumption     |   LN(CCI)   | LN(Consump) |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2017M01   |                       4.5 |  33,215,017.63 kr.  | 1.504077397 | 17.31851267 |
| 2017M02   |                       4.8 |  35,981,578.98 kr.  | 1.568615918 | 17.39851767 |
| 2017M03   |                       6.2 |  54,961,027.07 kr.  | 1.824549292 | 17.82213489 |
| 2017M04   |                       7.4 |  39,680,064.70 kr.  |     2.00148 | 17.49635947 |
| 2017M05   |                       5.8 |  34,272,294.13 kr.  | 1.757857918 | 17.34984783 |
| 2017M06   |                       7.1 |  33,543,793.70 kr.  | 1.960094784 | 17.32836242 |
| 2017M07   |                      10.5 |  43,976,684.81 kr.  | 2.351375257 | 17.59917016 |
| 2017M08   |                       7.6 |  42,991,206.24 kr.  | 2.028148247 | 17.57650615 |
| 2017M09   |                       7.3 |  46,268,968.39 kr.  | 1.987874348 | 17.64998207 |
| 2017M10   |                       7.1 |  47,737,723.24 kr.  | 1.960094784 | 17.68123249 |
| 2017M11   |                       7.6 |  84,451,560.04 kr.  | 2.028148247 | 18.25168867 |
| 2017M12   |                       6.5 |  84,466,488.61 kr.  | 1.871802177 | 18.25186543 |
| 2018M01   |                       8.2 |  32,688,045.95 kr.  | 2.104134154 |    17.30252 |
| 2018M02   |                       8.5 |  39,931,582.68 kr.  | 2.140066163 | 17.50267811 |
| 2018M03   |                       8.5 |  44,494,026.82 kr.  | 2.140066163 | 17.61086551 |
| 2018M04   |                       7.1 |  37,040,708.13 kr.  | 1.960094784 | 17.42752809 |
| 2018M05   |                       9.3 |  30,947,987.98 kr.  |   2.2300144 | 17.24781855 |
| 2018M06   |                      10.6 |  34,216,652.19 kr.  | 2.360854001 | 17.34822299 |
| 2018M07   |                       9.7 |  36,951,218.56 kr.  | 2.272125886 | 17.42510918 |
| 2018M08   |                       7.8 |  43,106,866.06 kr.  | 2.054123734 | 17.57919285 |
| 2018M09   |                       6.9 |  39,188,426.53 kr.  | 1.931521412 | 17.48389202 |
| 2018M10   |                       5.1 |  46,988,200.81 kr.  |  1.62924054 | 17.66540708 |
| 2018M11   |                       4.3 |  77,098,474.96 kr.  | 1.458615023 | 18.16059406 |
| 2018M12   |                       2.9 |  80,397,942.19 kr.  | 1.064710737 | 18.20249914 |
| 2019M01   |                       3.9 |  30,520,831.96 kr.  | 1.360976553 | 17.23392002 |
| 2019M02   |                       3.3 |  33,652,148.46 kr.  | 1.193922468 | 17.33158746 |
| 2019M03   |                       3.8 |  36,100,177.92 kr.  | 1.335001067 | 17.40180835 |
| 2019M04   |                       3.7 |  31,302,084.62 kr.  |  1.30833282 | 17.25919525 |
| 2019M05   |                       5.9 |  34,452,606.24 kr.  | 1.774952351 | 17.35509521 |
| 2019M06   |                       5.8 |  28,028,045.09 kr.  | 1.757857918 | 17.14871618 |
| 2019M07   |                       2.9 |  34,144,945.84 kr.  | 1.064710737 | 17.34612513 |
| 2019M08   |                       6.3 |  38,263,514.48 kr.  | 1.840549633 | 17.46000738 |
| 2019M09   |                       4.3 |  34,506,487.96 kr.  | 1.458615023 | 17.35665792 |
| 2019M10   |                       1.7 |  45,186,431.95 kr.  | 0.530628251 | 17.62630742 |
| 2019M11   |                       1.4 |  71,957,629.40 kr.  | 0.336472237 | 18.09158802 |
| 2019M12   |                       2.5 |  69,157,266.12 kr.  | 0.916290732 | 18.05189369 |
+-----------+---------------------------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Look into SARMAX models , also called Transfer Functions or Dynamic Regression . If you post your data I might be able to give you  more detail. See my following answer for threads https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353491/how-to-use-dynamic-regression-models-in-r-to-forecast-future-sales/353906#353906

Comment: @IrishStat Added the dataset - sorry for the slow reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plot of your output series CONS [image] visually suggesting 2 deterministic seasonal pulses (months 11 and 12 ) AND not a seasonal auto-projective scheme. Additionally there is a suggestion of a level shift not a downwards trend this no differencing. There is no indication of increased variance anywhere suggesting to need to do Weighted Least Squares OR or any form of a power transform like logs/square roots etc.

Now as a precursor to advanced causal model analytics a simple plot oy CONS and the candidate predictor CCI shows periods of a positive relationship and periods of an inverse relationship [image]  suggesting no consistent effect.

I used AUTOBOX ( which I have helped to develop) to systematically/automatically sort out a possible positive conclusion about the relationship/predictability between these two series. I will show the steps here.

The pre-whitened ( in this case since the predictor variable was free of autocorrelation  …  showing here the pw filter based on CCI [image]  ) we have [image] suggesting a simple model [image] which lead to the following deterministic structure being identified via Intervention Detection [image] culminating in this joint model [image] suggesting a decidedly non-significant CCI .

In order to test the hypothesis of constancy of the variance of the error process we use the TSAY test which considers deterministic change points here [image] and the Box-Cox test which considers linkages between the expected value and the variance of the errors here [image]

The final model is here [image] and here [image] with residual plot here [image] strongly suggesting randomness.

The Actual/Fit and Forecast graph is here [image]

Finally there is no apparent effect on Cons for any response to CCI changes  over time.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply - I'll need to read it through carefully and try to understand the software you've used before I accept your answer. I mainly turn to Python for these things :-)